# What's the best way to get latest tweets in iPhone(SDK, 3rd party libs, etc)?

Tags: iphone, twitter, tweets

I need to display a list of latest tweets in my iPhone app, and wondering what is the best way to do this, is there any SDK or existing projects doing this? I know about ShareKit, but it seems to be a method for sharing with standard UI, and no way to use it as a getter for latest tweets.

Thanks!

Comment: Twitter limits the rate at which you can hit their API. Are you looking for a latest tweets for a particular user or hashtag? Or are you just planning to consume all the data?

Comment: I need to get latest tweets for a particular user, thanks!

Comment: Then the answer below should work for you.. Just use `ASIHTTPRequest` to send a `POST` request to twitter and they'll return the results in a JSON format. You need to parse it using some JSON libraries and convert it into an object to do useful stuff, but that's the gist of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need to get publicly available data, then Twitter has a pretty straight-forward HTTP API that outputs JSON.

For example, to get a user's tweets: http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/public_timeline

You can easily use it by utilizing available library for JSON parsing (e.g. [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit)) and HTTP client (e.g. [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/), or `NSData`'s `+ dataWithContentsOfURL`).

Answer (score 1):

U see the following example.you will get some idea
  http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/twitter-api-iphone/

Answer (score 0):

There is also a third way, which is using http://three20.info/, that also implements main Twitter methods, but since all that you want is to retrieve public info I would stick with ASIHTTPRequest, as Barum Rho recommended. Easier and quicker.

Just to let you know more ways :)